# IGBT naming question

Tags: pnp, igbt

I was looking at this site http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/power/insulated-gate-bipolar-transistor.html

Here an IGBT is an NMOS with a BJT> But the BJT looks to be a pnp device. When the NMOS turns on, Vbe =0 , how will the pnp conduct? Making the gate negative, mean no channel exists in the NMOS, and the NMOS is off. The 2 ends could actually be at any potential. How does this circuit actually work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider it with a load.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fg4xD8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The base current of Q1 is determined by the hFE of Q1. \$V_{BE}\$ is about -0.75V, not 0V.

Comment: Is collector and emitter interchanged in the link?

Comment: I drew it the same as your link- the collector (C) of the approximate hybrid device is the emitter of Q1. This is only an approximation that illustrates the operation.

Comment: What happens to the voltages at the base and collectr of Q1 when M1 is off? Can they be any voltage?

Comment: The collector is grounded, so it's going to be at 0V by definition. The base will be Vbe of Q1 with leakage current through M1, so a couple hundred mV below the emitter of Q1 (and the latter will be at about +200V in the circuit shown).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following two states:

- When \$V_{GE}\$ is less than the threshold voltage of the MOSFET, \$I_B = 0\$, and therefore \$I_C = 0\$. The IGBT is **off**.
- When \$V_{GE}\$ is greater than the threshold voltage of the MOSFET, \$I_B\$ is set by the \$h_{FE}\$ of the BJT, and flows through the MOSFET. Therefore \$I_C = h_{FE} I_B\$; the IGBT is **on**.

Also, keep in mind that it is a *simplified equivalent circuit*. An actual IGBT is a PNPN (four-layer) semiconductor device. It's not just a BJT and MOSFET glued together in a box.